# О верхнем и нижнем индексах

Tags: обсуждение

На SO иногда возникает потребность в наборе формул. Понятно, что подключать громоздкий MathJax смысла нет. И в то же время сплошь и рядом в вопросах и ответах видим выражения типа **2^3**, хотя никто не мешает написать **2<sup>3</sup>**. С индексами ситуация не лучше.

На мой взгляд, причин тому две:

1. Отсутствие соответствующих пунктов меню в BBCode-панели.
2. Недостаточное внимание к вопросу со стороны участников сайта.

Возможно, что админы ruSO имеют доступ к настройке BBCode-панели. Также возможно, что теги **SUP** и **SUB** не исчерпывают ситуацию.
В то же время могут найтись причины, по которым следует оставить всё как есть.

Предлагаю обсудить вопрос.

P.S. Как бы то ни было, а [ответ в тему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/383716/%D0%9C%D0%9D%D0%9A-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC/639155#639155) пришлось писать через спецсимволы.

Comment: А я вот utf-8 цифирьки юзаю)

Comment: Бесспорно, нужно бы добавить в пункты панели ввода сообщение пункты верхний и нижний регистр. Но в заголовках ты не сможешь это использовать. По-этому, в заголовке нужно юзать utf8 циферки. А что тут обсуждать то?)

Comment: @Yuri, должно быть комплексное решение, чтобы в итоге было меньше правок и  больше ответов.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov, пиши на мету StackExchange и если у тебя будут голоса, то этот пункт добавят в панель

Comment: @Yuri Думаю, вопрос решается ближе. Например, в Mathematics есть MathJar.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov, вряд ли :)

Comment: @Yuri У нас свои админы есть, без их поддержки шевелиться глупо.

Comment: @vp_arth: utf-8 это кодировка (одна из многих). Unicode символы такие как ²³ (U+00B2, U+00B3), можно закодировать в байты, используя разные кодировки, а не только utf-8. Вы вероятно имели в виду "Unicode цифирьки".

Comment: @vp_arth не позорьтесь. Почитайте о том что такое Unicode.

Comment: @jfs можно и через спецсимволы HTML набрать: 2&sup3;

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov он называется [MathJa**x**](https://www.mathjax.org/), а не MathJar :)

Comment: @D-side до сих пор ассоциацию с Ajax не ощущал =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. BBCode-ов у нас нет, у нас StackOverflow Flavoured Markdown.
2. Редактор скорее всего никто править не будет без очень хорошей причины.
3. К счастью, решение есть в виде юзерскрипта [`<kbd>`, Superscript and Subscript, markup shortcuts](https://stackapps.com/questions/3341/kbd-superscript-and-subscript-markup-shortcuts).

   Он добавит вам на тулбар интересующие вас кнопки. И еще кнопку для тега `<kbd>`,  которым можно выделять обозначения хоткеев (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>) и элементов интерфейса (меню <kbd>Файл</kbd>).

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Alt+F4? это же закрытие окна

Comment: Кому как. У меня вот 4й tty открывается.

Comment: А <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>?

Comment: еще один юзер скрипт......у меня уже не первый.....смешно, что проще обложиться десятком-двумя юзерскриптов, чем что-то ждать от разрабов

Comment: Инетесующее вылеляние - это авторский стиль? :)

Comment: @alexolut ага, понедельничная дислексия. Еще бывает андроидная дислексия.

Comment: Уже неплохо. Осталось добиться, чтобы юзеры ставили юзерскрипты.